# How can I run test methods dynamically on runtime based on values from external file with NUnit?

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I have created a TestFixture class with two test methods.

```
[TestFixture]
class SomeTests
{   
        [Test]
        public void OpenScreen()
        { 
            //Do something
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestElement()
        { 
            //Do something
        }   
}
```

My requirement is to run these tests based on inputs from an external file which looks like:

```
Test    Value
Screen  "Scr1"
Element "Ele1"
Element "Ele2"
Screen  "Scr2"
Element "Ele3"
```

I am able to pass values to these test methods using:

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource("GetTestValues")]
public void OpenScreen(string value)
{ 
   //Do something
}
```

But I don't know how to run these tests in the exact order as received in the file. How can I achieve this?

```
Current order:

OpenScreen("Scr1")
OpenScreen("Scr2")
TestElement("Ele1")
TestElement("Ele2")
TestElement("Ele3")

Expected order:

OpenScreen("Scr1")
TestElement("Ele1")
TestElement("Ele2")
OpenScreen("Scr2")
TestElement("Ele3")
```

**Edit:** I'm using this for functional tests for testing some screens using Selenium.
The external file is a Json format string containing these values and `GetTestValues` simply deserializes the Json and returns the values.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, those test methods will be run by the NUnit runner and you won't be able to change the order in which they will run.

It seems what you are trying to do is to create some sort of acceptance test. What you can do is create a test method that wraps the sequence of steps and leave your `OpenScreen` and `TestElement` methods as simple helper methods:

```
[TestFixture]
class SomeTests
{   
    [Test]
    public void TestInteraction() {
        OpenScreen("Scr1")
        TestElement("Ele1")
        TestElement("Ele2")
        OpenScreen("Scr2")
        TestElement("Ele3")
    }

    private void OpenScreen(String arg)
    { 
        //Do something
    }

    private void TestElement()
    { 
        //Do something
    }   
}
```

There is the concept of "Page" objects, where you can write methods that represent actions you would perform on a screen or page. The `OpenScreen` and `TestElement` methods can be part of such object.